# Cannot SSH (using keys) as root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have a problem with log-in as a root user through SSH (using RSA key).
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

My sshd_config includes:

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password (tried "yes" as well)
PasswordAuthentication no
```

I have added PubKey to remote servers ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.
I have edited `~/.ssh/ (700) and authorized_keys (600)` file permissions.

Don't know where it goes wrong. I can ssh as a non-root user.

E: Added connection in detail.

```
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fc729e013b0), explicit, agent
debug2: key:  (0x7fc729f00740), agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Comment: try explicitly calling the private key file, with `ssh -i /key/dir/id_rsa root@hostname`. Maybe add to that `-v` or `-vv` too, which tell you what's actually happening as you try to authenticate and you can see what's going wrong. Include the output from that into your question with sensitive information redacted.

Comment: @Kefka I have tried already calling specific key file. No success. E: Also I have looked into connection using verbose parameters, every time a key is sent, packet type 51 is received.

Comment: then provide (sanitized) verbose output with `ssh -vv root@hostname`. That will give more to work with for finding the problem.

Besides that, just to rule out the obvious, you are restarting sshd each time you change the config on the remote server, right?

Comment: Yes, I have reloaded sshd.

Comment: I'm at work and can't play around to test myself right now, but take a look at the second answer (by username Jah) in this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131886/ssh-public-key-wont-send-to-server. I'm not sure how you copied the key over, but if it was other than `ssh-copy-id` then a fatfinger could cause it.

Comment: Sure, thanks! I added it manually but definitely checked multiple times that key is correct.